# Finding a solution to a system

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers, systems-of-equations, linear-programming

Let $i$ be of the form $i=2^a3^b5^c$, where $a,b,c\ge 0$ are integers.

Consider numbers $x_{i,4},x_{i,6}$ where $x_{i,6}$ is defined when $2$ or $3$ divides $i$, $x_{i,4}$ is defined only when $2$ divides $i$.

The constraints are

1. If $2$ divides $i$, then $$x_{i, 4} + x_{i,6} \le \frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{5}}{i}$$
2. If $3$ divides $i$ but $2$ doesn't divide $i$, then $$x_{i,6} \le \frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{5}}{i}$$
3. $$\sum x_{i,4} = \sum x_{i,6} = \frac{1}{6}.$$

I know that this system has a solution, but the technique doesn't work when I include more $x_{i,j}$'s. I've never solved systems of this type; what's a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: I'm a little confused. If $i = 5$, then $x_{i, 4}$ and $x_{i, 6}$ are both undefined, right? But from what you've written, I'm not sure I can figure out what values $x_{10, 4}$, $x_{30, 6}$, $x_{12, 4}$, $x_{30, 6}$, etc., are supposed to have.

Comment: @DavidR. Yes, they're both undefined if $i=5$. I'm not asking for explicit values of $x_{i,j}$ when $j=4,6$, I'm just asking whether they can be chosen such that conditions 1-3 are satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this system have no solution, first $x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3,x_5,y_5 \in \mathbb{R} \geq 0$.

And $x_2+y_2=1 = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$

And $x_3+y_3 = \frac{1}{2} =  \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^k}$

And $x_5 +y_5 = \frac{1}{4} = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{5^k}$.

So $\sum x_{i,4} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{5}* \frac{1}{2} * ((x_2+1)(x_3+1)(x_5+1)-(x_3+1)(x_5+1))$ because if $2\not|i$ then its not defined for $x_{i,4}$.

And $\sum x_{i,6} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{5}* \frac{1}{3} * ((y_2+1)(y_3+1)(y_5+1)-(y_5+1))$ because if $2\not|i$ and $3\not|i$ then its not defined for $x_{i,6}$.

Solving this system of equations using Wolfram|Alpha (also simplex method works) yield that there is **no solution** for your system.

Comment: I apologize but I made a edit. In the constraints 1,2 I corrected the denominators. There should be a solution in that case. Can you comment on how the simplex can be used here?

Comment: yes, you will arrive at the same equations i have posted , but now you get that $\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{5} * ((x_2+1)(x_3+1)(x_5+1)-(x_3+1)(x_5+1)) \geq \frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{5} * ((y_2+1)(y_3+1)(y_5+1)-(y_5+1)) \geq \frac{1}{6}$ and $x_2+y_2=1$ and $x_3+y_3=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x_5+y_5=\frac{1}{4}$  also $x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3,x_5,y_5 \in \mathbb{R} \geq 0$  and the simplex method is used to solve such equations (see a online videos because it need a little bit learning )

Comment: these are all the solution to your new system : $\left(\text{x5}=0\land \left(\left(\text{x3}=0\land \frac{5}{8}\leq \text{x2}\leq
   1\right)\lor \left(0<\text{x3}\leq \frac{1}{2}\land \frac{5}{8
   \text{x3}+8}\leq \text{x2}\leq \frac{15-20 \text{x3}}{15-10
   \text{x3}}\right)\right)\right)\lor \left(0<\text{x5}\leq \frac{1}{4}\land
   0\leq \text{x3}\leq \frac{1}{2}\land \frac{5}{8 \text{x3} \text{x5}+8
   \text{x3}+8 \text{x5}+8}\leq \text{x2}\leq \frac{16 \text{x3} \text{x5}-20
   \text{x3}-16 \text{x5}+15}{8 \text{x3} \text{x5}-10 \text{x3}-12
   \text{x5}+15}\right)$

Comment: thank you. Can you explain how you arrived at the equations for $\sum {x_i,4}, \sum x_{i,6}$? Why do you set them $\ge \frac{1}{6}$ instead of $\le \frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Because constrains 1 and 2 requires that $x_{i,4}$ and $x_{i,6}$ be smaller or equal to some value so if we solve for $\leq \frac{1}{6}$ then we kind of making sure that $\sum x_{i,4}$ and $\sum x_{i,6}$ are less than $\frac{1}{6}$, to put it in intuitive way suppose $\sum x_{i,4} = \frac{1}{2}$ then we could multiply every $x_{i,4}$ by $\frac{1}{3}$ to reach $\frac{1}{6}$ without breaking the constrain since it allow that $x_{i,4}$ be smaller than some value but if for instance   $\sum x_{i,4} = \frac{1}{12}$ then we cant multiply by $2$ since then we are not sure that we did not break (c) 1.

Comment: Also the solution i wrote in the comment is by Wolfram|Alpha using simplex optimization method, if its too much, i suggest you put $x_3,x_5$ to $0$ or just one of them ,then you will end up with $2$ inequalities with $2$ unknown which is easy solve-able and produces a beautiful solutions.

Comment: 1 last question, can you explain the reason for adding 1's to the $x_k, y_k$?

Comment: gladly see this i want to present all number of the form $i =2^a 3^b$ for all $a,b>0$ so to start i have $1/2+1/4+1/8+\cdots = \sum \frac{1}{2^k}$ but don't forget also $1/6+1/12+1/24+\cdots = \sum \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2^k}$ and so on, so we are expanding this formula $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^j} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$ but we are missing one last sequence namely $1/3+1/9+1/27+\cdots$ thus we need to add one to the $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$ making it $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}$, or simply because when we multiply $(1/2+1/4+1/8+...)$ by $(1/3+1/9+1/27+..)$.

Comment: we are considering $i=2^a 3^b$ such that $a,b\geq 1$ so we must add to this the sum $1/2+1/4+1/8+...$ and $1/3+1/9+1/27+...$ , try to expand $(1/2+1/4+1/8+...)(1/3+1/9+1/27+....)$ to understand what i am saying,thanks and hopes you gets it.